# Verify that each record has the same Value for each login

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
ID  |             LastAccessed         |   loginID   |
======================================================
1   |      02-15-2018 16:00:45:300     |    admin    |
2   |      02-15-2018 16:00:45:300     |    admin    |
3   |      02-15-2018 18:44:55:108     |    johny    |
4   |      02-15-2018 11:52:34:206     |    sarah    |
5   |      02-15-2018 11:52:34:206     |    sarah    |
6   |      02-15-2018 11:52:34:206     |    sarah    |
7   |      02-15-2018 11:52:34:206     |    sarah    |
```

In this table I want to verify that every `loginID` has the same value for all of its corresponding `LastAccessed` values.

For example, we see that `admin` and `sarah` have the same `LastAccessed` value. I'm guessing we can get two counts and verify that they are the same?

I need to verify this for a set of about 8,000 records.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or you can try distinct group by combination like below

```
select loginId 
from table
group by loginId
having count(distinct LastAccessed) >1;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the `loginId`s that have different values using:

```
select loginId
from t
group by loginId
having min(LastAccessed) <> max(LastAccessed);
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach, you can try like following.

```
SELECT Count(*) DistCount ,LoginId,LastAccessed         
FROM [LOGIN]
GROUP BY LastAccessed ,LoginId
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

This query will give you all the LoginId having more that one `LoginId,LastAccessed`  combination.

If you only need `Login` as output. You can change the query like following.

```
SELECT DISTINCT LoginId
FROM 
(
    SELECT Count(*) DistCount ,LoginId,LastAccessed         
    FROM [LOGIN]
    GROUP BY LastAccessed ,LoginId
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1       
) T
```

Comment: That sounds like thats what I want. I'll try this query in 12 hours once I get back in the environment. Is "DisCount" a typo.... Never heard of such a keyword in sql. Distinct you mean

Comment: DistCount  is the alias name given to the count column. You can choose any column name. It's not a keyword